# How to change a global CSS Bootstrap in specific component in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I used bootstrap-vue toast to shows success message.

```
<b-toast id="example-toast" title="BootstrapVue" static no-auto-hide>
  Hello, world! This is a toast message.
</b-toast>
```

I added this CSS to show it on `top: 90px`

```
.b-toaster.b-toaster-top-right,
.b-toaster.b-toaster-top-left,
.b-toaster.b-toaster-top-center,
.b-toaster.b-toaster-top-full{
  top: 90px;
}
```

Just in one component need `top: 50px`
But when add new CSS in specific component,

```
.b-toaster.b-toaster-top-right,
.b-toaster.b-toaster-top-left,
.b-toaster.b-toaster-top-center,
.b-toaster.b-toaster-top-full{
  top: 50px;
}
```

It will be changed in all other components.
How is possible to change the CSS only on one component (`top: 50px`) and other components have `top: 90px`?

Comment: you can use scoped as mentioned here https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html

Comment: scoped doesn't work. because toast element appears in body not in the component element.

Comment: then you can use style binding like this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325246/vue-how-to-change-style-of-a-same-element-in-different-components

Comment: I said in  here one specific component. I may use it in more than 20 components. By the way depend on  page design should have different tops. Not sure your suggestion is the best way.

Comment: Try to use <div id="example-toast" class="classA"></div>

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two ways here:

The better way:

Use a custom class name like `class='myCustomAlert'` and in your `global.css`:

```
.myCustomAlert {
    top: 50px !important;
}
```

Another way( This one is **deprecated** but exactly your situation )

Use `/deep/` selector:

```
/deep/ .b-toaster.b-toaster-top-right,
       .b-toaster.b-toaster-top-left,
       .b-toaster.b-toaster-top-center,
       .b-toaster.b-toaster-top-full {
           top: 50px;
       }
```

I do not recommend using `/deep/` selector but it's good for you to know.

Comment: As I commented before, deep works  only if your element be in the component element. But toast element s in  inside the body tag so deep is not working.